# Verb Patterns - Gerundium x infitiv

Tags: verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

I am preparing for CAE exam, can anyone tell me what's the difference between these two sentences?
The first sentence should be correct. Is the second sentence possible as well?

> British people are commonly believed to be weak at foreign languages
>   British people are commonly believed to being weak at foreign languages.

Comment: In some cases, a gerund and an infinitive can be used interchangeably, e.g. "She is happy _to be_ a teacher." and "She is happy _being_ a teacher." However, this is not one of those cases; the second sentence is incorrect. I do not have a good reason why other than, it sounds wrong (hence posting only as a comment), but perhaps another user can help explain.

Comment: "Are commonly believed to be ..." is fine; it's a passive clause where "to" is a clause subordinator. But the clause subordinator "to" introduces infinitival clauses, not gerund-participial ones like "being weak at languages". And it's not a preposition either since "believe" doesn't license a PP headed by "to". But note that you could say "the British people have admitted to being weak at languages", where the prep "to" is licensed (permitted) by "admitted".